# Issue with message container width CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to show a message on the `top - center` of my web page. I create a very basic example :

http://jsbin.com/eniwax/3/edit

Here the problem is with message container with. I want to set the container width equals to the message text width means ( auto, width vary according to the size of message ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wHazG/)

Explanation: Use a nested div and make the container div width as 100% and give `text-align: center;` to the container div

CSS

```
.test {
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 1px solid #F0C36D;
    background-color: #F9EDBE;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding : 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="test">I am a sample text</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<span />` inside your div rather than a `<div />` on it's own.

Divs are block level elements which means they fill all the available width that they have. Spans are inline which means they are only as wide as their contents.

Comment: While this is true, simply changing to a `span` will not align the element centrally.

Answer (score 0):

#### Give `display: inline-block;` and `text-align: center;` to the parent.

```
body {text-align: center;}
.test
{
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 1px solid #F0C36D;
    background-color: #F9EDBE;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding : 4px;

}
```

#### Demo: http://jsbin.com/eniwax/15